# Postgresql extract monthYear from a date to be compared

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

```
WHERE to_char(startDate, 'MM-YYYY') BETWEEN '04-2017' AND '06-2017'
```

This code is working, but it's right?

Or I have to extract the month and year separately as a number?

Comment: it is better to use `startDate >= date '2017-04-01' and startDate <= date '2017-06-30'`

Comment: The problem is that the user pass only the month Year.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you need the format to by yyyymm not mmyyyy:

```
WHERE to_char(startDate, 'YYYY-MM') BETWEEN '2017-04' AND '2017-06'
```

The better way to write this is with explicit date comparisons:

```
WHERE startDate >= '2017-04-01'::date AND
      startDate < '2017-07-01'::date
```

This allows the optimizer to use an index on `startDate`.  Moreover, it works regardless of whether or not there is a time component on `startDate`.

Comment: Thumbs up for the second option. It's important that people think in the data types they have without converting each time through 10 conversion processes.